# How do I access variables displayed in devel?

Tags: 7, theming, debugging

Using devel I'm able to retrieve the names of certain variables and how to access them.

For example I might want to use the book menu name. Devel has it listed as so

```
$...->book['menu_name']
```

But I'm not sure how to print that info in page.tpl.php or access it in general. I'm also not sure what to replace the $... with.

I've tried the following with no luck.

```
print $page->book['menu_name'];
print $node->book['menu_name'];
print render($page->book['menu_name']);
print render($node->book['menu_name']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do any theming to node use node.tpl.php instead of page.tpl.php

in page it is not suggested. If you want to render a field in node.tpl just write the following

```
<?php print render($content['menu_name'])?>
```

or simply

```
<?php print $node->book['menu_name']; ?>
```

Comment: I'm still not sure how to use these methods using the $..->book items. With the page.tpl method if I wanted book['menu_item'] would I write $page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$node->book]['menu_name'] ? and in node.tpl would it be print render($content->book['menu_name'])?

Comment: can you explain what is book? is it a content type that has field menu_name?

Comment: It's one of the modules for creating child pages, but if you're unfamiliar with it, we could do the same thing with the body field. The actual content of the body of the content is listed as $...->body['und'][0]['value'] but I'm not sure where to put the ->body part is I'm already using nid for $node->nid

Comment: Are you using book module? if nothing works then I would suggest to print_r(variable) and print it as it is without render function. I honestly don't get your last comment :(

Comment: I'm using devel to grab the variables available on the current page. Here's a screenshot http://imgur.com/fccUoZF

Comment: In the screenshot the value ($...->body['und'][0]['value'] under 'body>und>0' is expanded and what I'm referring to.

Comment: You have no problem with rendering body, where is book. Can you give me a screenshot of book field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32457/discussion-between-shabir-and-matt).

Comment: It says you're not currently in the room. Here's a screenshot of the book field http://imgur.com/tCLpdnR also I'm not planning on rendering it, I would just like to have access to the value so I can do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think $content['body']['#object']->book['menu_name'];  is what you're looking for. Here is an example using it to render the parent book menu.

```
<?php
$menuName = $content['body']['#object']->book['menu_name'];
print drupal_render(menu_tree($menuName));
?>
```